# Actualizar el valor de una celda en un dataframe en R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando rellenar los valores de una variable fila por fila para lo cual recorro el dataframe y cuando tengo el valor que quiero rellenar hago esto:

```
listadoProyectosPlanificados<-function(df){
variables<-names(df)
variablesAIgnorar<-c('Total','JefeProyecto','Ranking','Proyectos')
variablesATenerEncuenta<-subset(variables,!(variables %in% variablesAIgnorar))
for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
 proyectos<-vector()
 for (indiceColumna in 1:length(variablesATenerEncuenta)) {
  if (df[indiceFila,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna]]!=0) {
    proyectos<-append(proyectos,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna])
  }
}
print(indiceFila)
print(ncol(df))
print(paste(proyectos,collapse = ', '))
df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
}
}
```

En los prints que tengo para ver como va la cosa todo va bien
[image: prints]

Pero la instrucción

```
df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
```

No me está añadiendo los valores sin embargo si yo hago en consola esto

```
df[1,49]<-paste(c('hola','adios'),collapse = ', ')

> df[1,49]
[1] "hola, adios"
```

Si que actualiza

Alguna idea por favor?

Un saludo

Comment: Seria estupendo que puedas incluir una pequeña muestra del dataset para ver que se busca `df<- read.table(text=" col1 col2 col3  10 20 30    ", fill=TRUE, header=TRUE)` ya que viendo la estructura de datos se te puede ayudar mejor con las consultas a la misma (el 10 20 y 30 son en una nueva línea)

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta no es suficientemente clara.

En la forma que la entiendo, comento que las funciones crean un "environment" propio. Lo que asigna dentro de la función queda dentro de la función y se pierde para el "environment" desde el que fue llamado. Lo que devuelve la función es la última instrucción.
Puede añadir, al final, antes de la última llave de cierre: return(df)

```
}
return(df)
}
```

Esto deja explicito qué debe devolver la función.

Comment: Esa no es la ultima instrucción de la función. Esa instrucción está dentro de un bucle. La función recorre en un bucle for todas las filas y por cada fila recorre una serie de columnas, obteniendo una serie de valores y al final del bucle de columnas, esos valores obtenidos intento asignarlos a una celda concreta de la fila tratada. Eso por cada fila y esa asignación no me funciona por que la celda no se actualiza

Comment: La solución es devolver al final el dataframe. return (df)

Answer (score 0):

La solución es devolver al final de la función el dataframe completo

```
listadoProyectosPlanificados<-function(df){
variables<-names(df)
variablesAIgnorar<-c('Total','JefeProyecto','Ranking','Proyectos')
variablesATenerEncuenta<-subset(variables,!(variables %in% variablesAIgnorar))
for (indiceFila in 1:nrow(df)) {
proyectos<-vector()
for (indiceColumna in 1:length(variablesATenerEncuenta)) {
  if (df[indiceFila,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna]]!=0) {
    proyectos<-append(proyectos,variablesATenerEncuenta[indiceColumna])
  }
}
df[indiceFila,ncol(df)]<-paste(proyectos,collapse = ', ')
}
return(df)
}
```